# Translating SiDiF to Weaviate

Tags: uml, ontology, weaviate

I have several ontology descriptions in [Simple Data Interchange Format](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/SiDIF) and would like to transform or import these to use them with Weaviate.

An example can be found at:

http://cr.bitplan.com/index.php/CrSchema#sidif (see source code below).

I was able to create classes and properties manually but i am not sure how to do relations in Weaviates Schema description style. E.g. if i have a class "Event" and want to link the City for it **how do i do this if at all?**

You'll find more details on the schema at http://cr.bitplan.com/index.php/Concept:Event and there is also an UML diagram for it:
[image: UML Diagram]
which is also available at http://diagrams.bitplan.com/render/png/0x2637ba5e.png.

**Would it be possible to convert the domain core of SiDIF files to Weaviate Schema style in general?**

**CrSchema**

```sh
#
# Context:CrSchema
#
CrSchema isA Context
"CrSchema" is name of it
"http://cr.bitplan.com" is master of it
"2020-07-22" is since of it
#
# Event
#
Event isA Topic
"Event" is name of it
"Events" is pluralName of it
"a meeting of researchers at a specific time and place" is documentation of it
"a meeting of researchers at a specific time and place (virtual or physical) and with a specific thematic focus to present, hear and discuss research outputs " is wikiDocumentation of it
"File:EventLogo-64px.png" is icon of it
"/images/cr/e/e0/EventLogo-64px.png" is iconUrl of it
"property" is defaultstoremode of it
"CrSchema" is context of it
Event_acronym addsTo it
# properties of Event
# property acronym
Event_acronym isA Property
"acronym" is name of it
"acronym" is label of it
"text" is type of it
1 is index of it
1 is sortPos of it
true is primaryKey of it
false is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The official acronym of the academic event, if it has one. " is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"Event" is topic of it
# property wikidataid
Event_wikidataid isA Property
"wikidataid" is name of it
"wikidataid" is label of it
"text" is type of it
2 is index of it
false is primaryKey of it
false is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The wikidataid of the event" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"Event" is topic of it
#
# City
#
City isA Topic
"City" is name of it
"Cities" is pluralName of it
"large permanent human settlement" is documentation of it
"[https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q515 large permanent human settlement]" is wikiDocumentation of it
"property" is defaultstoremode of it
"File:CityIcon-64px.png" is icon of it
"/images/cr/9/9e/CityIcon-64px.png" is iconUrl of it
"CrSchema" is context of it
City_name addsTo it
City_wikidataid addsTo it
# properties of City
# property name
City_name isA Property
"name" is name of it
"name" is label of it
"text" is type of it
1 is index of it
1 is sortPos of it
true is primaryKey of it
true is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The name of the city" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"City" is topic of it
# property wikidataid
City_wikidataid isA Property
"wikidataid" is name of it
"wikidataid" is label of it
"text" is type of it
2 is index of it
false is primaryKey of it
false is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The wikidataid of the city" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"City" is topic of it
#
# Country
#
Country isA Topic
"Country" is name of it
"Countries" is pluralName of it
"distinct region in geography; a broad term that can include political divisions or regions associated with distinct political characteristics" is documentation of it
"[https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6256 distinct region in geography; a broad term that can include political divisions or regions associated with distinct political characteristics]" is wikiDocumentation of it
"File:CountryIcon-64px.png" is icon of it
"/images/cr/4/4c/CountryIcon-64px.png" is iconUrl of it
"property" is defaultstoremode of it
"CrSchema" is context of it
Country_name addsTo it
Country_wikidataid addsTo it
# properties of Country
# property name
Country_name isA Property
"name" is name of it
"name" is label of it
"text" is type of it
1 is index of it
1 is sortPos of it
true is primaryKey of it
true is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The name of the Country" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"Country" is topic of it
# property wikidataid
Country_wikidataid isA Property
"wikidataid" is name of it
"wikidataid" is label of it
"text" is type of it
2 is index of it
false is primaryKey of it
false is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The wikidataid of the Country" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"Country" is topic of it
#
# State
#
State isA Topic
"State" is name of it
"States" is pluralName of it
"territorial and constitutional community forming part of a federal union" is documentation of it
"[https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q107390 territorial and constitutional community forming part of a federal union]" is wikiDocumentation of it
"File:StateIcon-64px.png" is icon of it
"/images/cr/f/fe/StateIcon-64px.png" is iconUrl of it
"property" is defaultstoremode of it
"CrSchema" is context of it
State_name addsTo it
State_wikidataid addsTo it
# properties of State
# property name
State_name isA Property
"name" is name of it
"name" is label of it
"text" is type of it
1 is index of it
1 is sortPos of it
true is primaryKey of it
true is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The name of the State" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"State" is topic of it
# property wikidataid
State_wikidataid isA Property
"wikidataid" is name of it
"wikidataid" is label of it
"text" is type of it
2 is index of it
false is primaryKey of it
false is mandatory of it
50 is size of it
false is uploadable of it
"The wikidataid of the State" is documentation of it
false is isLink of it
"State" is topic of it
#
# TopicLinks
#
# Event n : 1 City
Event_in_City isA TopicLink
"eventInCity" is name of it
"city" is sourceRole of it
false is sourceMultiple of it
"City" is source of it
"event" is targetRole of it
true is targetMultiple of it
"Event" is target of it 
# Event n : 1 State
Event_in_State isA TopicLink
"eventInState" is name of it
"state" is sourceRole of it
false is sourceMultiple of it
"State" is source of it
"event" is targetRole of it
true is targetMultiple of it
"Event" is target of it 
# Event n : 1 Country
Event_in_Country isA TopicLink
"eventInCountry" is name of it
"country" is sourceRole of it
false is sourceMultiple of it
"Country" is source of it
"event" is targetRole of it
true is targetMultiple of it
"Event" is target of it
```

Comment: see also http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Weaviate

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define a reference property. These have the referenced class as `dataType`. E.g. for referencing a city:

```
{
  "name": "inCity",
  "description": "city reference",
  "dataType": [
    "City"
  ],
  "cardinality": "many"
}
```

Then you can add references via a beacon:

```sh
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/v1/things/c60505f9-8271-4eec-b998-81d016648d85/references/hasEvent" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"beacon": "weaviate://localhost/things/2a8d56b7-2dd5-4e68-aa40-53c9196aecde"}'
```

In this example the property `hasEvent` of thing the object with uuid `c60505f9-8271-4eec-b998-81d016648d85` is referencing the object with uuid `2a8d56b7-2dd5-4e68-aa40-53c9196aecde`.

Check the [reference documentation](https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/add-data/add_and_modify.html#references-guide) for more infos.

Here is a minimal example using the python client:

```py
#pip install weaviate-client==0.4.0
import weaviate
import time

schema = {
  "things": {
    "type": "thing",
    "classes": [
      {
        "class": "Event",
        "description": "event",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "acronym",
            "description": "acronym",
            "dataType": [
              "text"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "inCity",
            "description": "city reference",
            "dataType": [
              "City"
            ],
            "cardinality": "many"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "class": "City",
        "description": "city",
        "properties": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "description": "name",
            "dataType": [
              "text"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "hasEvent",
            "description": "event references",
            "dataType": [
              "Event"
            ],
            "cardinality": "many"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


client = weaviate.Client("http://localhost:8080")

if not client.contains_schema():
    client.create_schema(schema)

event = {"acronym": "example"}
client.create(event, "Event", "2a8d56b7-2dd5-4e68-aa40-53c9196aecde")
city = {"name": "Amsterdam"}
client.create(city, "City", "c60505f9-8271-4eec-b998-81d016648d85")

time.sleep(2.0)
client.add_reference("c60505f9-8271-4eec-b998-81d016648d85", "hasEvent", "2a8d56b7-2dd5-4e68-aa40-53c9196aecde")
```

> Would it be possible to convert the domain core of SiDIF files to Weaviate Schema style in general?

This depends on your use-case and the amount of work that you want to put in.

- If you are only interested in the semantic capabilities:
  In this case you might not need to build an elaborate schema at all. It might be enough to just create 4 classes `subject`, `predicate`, `object` and `triple` and load everything like so.
- You want to load a specific set of definitions:
  You have to replicate the vocabulary of interest in as a weaviate schema. Weaviate does not support class inheritance so you'd have to define these somehow over references. If you have a cleanly defined vocabulary this should be relatively straight forward.
- You want to dynamically load all kinds of vocabularies:
  I am not entirely sure if that is easily achievable. I'd assume that you have to build a very elaborate parser.

Hope this helps cheers.